# Is this problem match with bridge design pattern

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, database-design

So I want to design a data class for storing network information. Network information should store something like this.

```
data class PatrickNetwork(
  @Id
  val networkId: String,
  val name: String,
  val description: String,
  val vlan: Int,
  val networkType: NetworkType,
  val networkInfo: NetworkInfo
)

enum class NetworkType {
  BRIDGE,
  PEERING
}
```

the other fields are fine, but the problem is on the network info field which depends on the network type. This is how it should store

```
// for bridge type
data class NetworkInfo(
  val ipv4Cidr: String,
  val bridgeIP: List<String>
)
// for peering type
data class NetworkInfo(
  val ipv4Cidr: String,
  val customerIP: String,
  val organizeIP: String
)
```

I have tried applying the bridge design pattern to my code and I got this

```
data class PatrickNetwork(
  @Id
  val networkId: String,
  val name: String,
  val description: String,
  val vlan: Int,
  val networkType: NetworkType,
  val networkInfo: IPatrickNetworkInfo
)

interface IPatrickNetworkInfo {
   val ipv4Cidr: String
}

data class BridgeNetworkInfo(
  override val ipv4Cidr: String,
  val bridgeIP: List<String>
): IPatrickNetworkInfo

data class PeeringNetworkInfo(
  override val ipv4Cidr: String,
  val customerIP: String,
  val organizeIP: String
): IPatrickNetworkInfo
```

So I'm very new to design pattern am I doing it wrong or miss understanding the concept or are there any design pattern that fit better for this problem

Comment: Data classes aren't object oriented, so OO design patterns won't really help you. Objects _hide_ data, rather than share it and expose it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand that's not a bridge pattern, there you'd have an extra abstract class encapsulating the interface. But that's good, since I don't see any point in doing that here anyway.

The interface and it's implementations seem sensible. What I would change though is remove the networkType property and the enum since this information is redundant. In fact it's dangerous since you could set networkType to PEERING yet use BridgeNetworkInfo and it would compile fine.

Instead of an enum you can make IPatrickNetworkInfo a sealed interface (if it's not sealed it will still work, but require a lot of pointless else{} branches), this will allow you to match (with `when`) on the implementation of IPatrickNetworkInfo, just like you could do with that enum, but now you are guaranteed that the information is actually correct.